# Select if count condition

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm trying to select a "station" item if it has more than 4 sub elements of "Bett" with the attribute "Belegt" set to "false". The sub elements should be counted in total.

```
./Krankenhaus/Station[count(//Bett[@Belegt='true'])>4]
```

This results in returning all stations. Which is not correct

This is the XML im working with.

```
<Krankenhaus>
    <Station S_ID="1" Leitung="3">
        <Name>Notaufnahme</Name>
        <Standort>vorort</Standort>
        <Telefonnummer>+43 732 93353555582</Telefonnummer>
        <Leitbild>Schnellstmögliche Versorgung</Leitbild>
    </Station>
    <Station S_ID="2" Leitung="4">
        <Name>Rehabilitation</Name>
        <Standort>extern</Standort>
        <Telefonnummer>+43 732 933522246739954</Telefonnummer>
        <Besuchszeit>täglich 9.00-11.00 und 15.00-17.00</Besuchszeit>
        <Leitbild>
            Bestmögliche Rahmenbedingungen zur vollständigen Rehabilitation
        </Leitbild>
        <Beschreibung>Genesungsfreudliche Umgebung</Beschreibung>
        <Patientenzimmer>
            <Zimmer Z_ID="20105">
                <Stockwerk>1</Stockwerk>
                <Kategorie>A</Kategorie>
                <Klasse>2</Klasse>
                <MaxBetten>4</MaxBetten>
                <Betten>
                    <Bett B_ID="201" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="202" Belegt="false"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="203" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="204" Belegt="false"/>
                </Betten>
            </Zimmer>
            <Zimmer Z_ID="20106">
                <Stockwerk>1</Stockwerk>
                <Kategorie>C</Kategorie>
                <Klasse>2</Klasse>
                <MaxBetten>5</MaxBetten>
                <Betten>
                    <Bett B_ID="205" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="206" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="207" Belegt="true"/>
                </Betten>
            </Zimmer>
            <Zimmer Z_ID="20107">
                <Stockwerk>1</Stockwerk>
                <Kategorie>C</Kategorie>
                <Klasse>2</Klasse>
                <MaxBetten>5</MaxBetten>
                <Ausstattung>Balkon</Ausstattung>
                <Betten>
                    <Bett B_ID="2010" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="2011" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="2012" Belegt="true"/>
                    <Bett B_ID="2013" Belegt="false"/>
                </Betten>
            </Zimmer>
        </Patientenzimmer>
    </Station>
</Krankenhaus>
```

Comment: Instead of `count(//Bett` use `count(Bett`: `//` means anywhere in the document.

Comment: The example comes from an XQuery introduction which is very good, but perhaps not that well known: Wolfgang Lehner/Harald Schöning, XQuery: Grundlagen und fortgeschrittene Methoden. dpunkt Verlag, 2004. See https://www.dpunkt.de/buecher/2057/xquery.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context Node

A slash at the start of the path always indicates an implicit root query. Translated to English language, your query translates to something like (*Krankenhaus* means hospital, *Station* has the same meaning, *Bett* is a bed, *belegt*  means occupied):

> Select all hospital's stations if there are at least four occupied beds (in all hospitals).

Instead, start a search at the current context `.`, which can be done explicitly:

```
./Krankenhaus/Station[count(./Patientenzimmer/Zimmer/Betten/Bett[@Belegt='true'])>4]
```

or implicitly (see the missing `./` introducing the subpath):

```
./Krankenhaus/Station[count(Patientenzimmer/Zimmer/Betten/Bett[@Belegt='true'])>4]
```

Of course, you can also use the `descendant-or-self` axis `//`, which I replaced in the examples above to explain the implicit context. If you want to stick with cutting short the path to the beds, do

```
./Krankenhaus/Station[count(.//Bett[@Belegt='true'])>4]
```

### Context and Root Node

Finally, I'd remove the leading context node `.` at the beginning of your query, as you start your search at the root node anyway. By not putting it there (which technically is totally fine, as the default context *is* the root node), you can be more concise on what you really want to do:

```
/Krankenhaus/Station[count(.//Bett[@Belegt='true'])>4]
```